# Ungroup SmartArt using PowerAutomate

Tags: linux, automation, powerpoint, power-automate

I have multiple PowerPoint files which has SmartArts in them. I want to ungroup these SmartArts into shapes using Power Automate. Please let me know if this is possible.

Furthermore, I would also like to know if this can also be done in linux systems in which PowerPoint is not installed.

I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Anyway, yeah you can probably do it in Power Automate for Desktop. But that's not on Linux. If you wanted to do it on Linux with no PowerPoint client installed, you'd have to decipher the SmartArt XML and convert to standard AutoShapes via the file format. That would probably work fine as smart art uses standard preset geometries, with the exception of probably the text boxes in SmartArt—their margins don't match standard AutoShapes' text boxes.